# Trying to change row2 on my csv file in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, csv

So I'm building an atm machine in python for school. Everything works great except for when I want to deposit/withdraw money. My loop just wipes the whole csv file clean and only the latest entry is there.

So what I'm trying to do is to copy my csv to a list and then make the changes in the right row, and then write it back to the csv, with the new changes.

Im really stuck here.. =/ But heres my code:

```
def changeBalance(username):

    with open("accounts.csv") as inf:
        reader = csv.reader(inf.readlines())

    with open("accounts.csv", "w") as inf:
        amount = input("Ange belopp: ₹ ")
        writer = csv.writer(inf)

        for line in reader:
            if line[0] == username:
                newBalance = str(float(line[2]) + float(amount))
                line[2] = newBalance
                writer.writerow(line)
                print("\nInsatt summa: ₹",(amount) ,(today), (nowTime))
                print (f"Aktuellt saldo: ₹ {newBalance}")
                break
```

Comment: Open the file in append mode: `with open("accounts.csv", "a") as inf:`

Comment: @Mike67 i could be wrong but i dont think that would work if he's replacing existing values.

Comment: appending would add a new row, not change the existing one =/

Answer (score 0):

Without looking too far into the code, your reader and writer are referring to the same file.

1. Would it be acceptable if it's written to a different file? I would try that out.
2. If you want the same filename, I would just replace the original file after the new one is done.

Answer (score 0):

When ending a file with data that can change size, you have to read the whole file in, change the data, and write the whole file out again.  The current code only writes one line back out.

```
import csv

def changeBalance(username):

    # read all the lines
    with open('accounts.csv', 'r', newline='') as inf:
        lines = list(csv.reader(inf))

    with open('accounts.csv', 'w', newline='') as outf:
        amount = float(input('Ange belopp: ₹ '))
        writer = csv.writer(outf)

        # process lines
        for line in lines:
            if line[0] == username: # change the amount for just this line
                line[2] = float(line[2]) + amount
                print(f'\nInsatt summa: ₹ {amount}')
                print(f'Aktuellt saldo: ₹ {line[2]}')
            writer.writerow(line) # but write every line out

changeBalance('user1')
changeBalance('user2')

with open('accounts.csv') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Test accounts.csv:

```
user1,col2,100.0,col3,col4
user2,col2,200.0,col3,col4
```

Output:

```
Ange belopp: ₹ 5

Insatt summa: ₹ 5.0
Aktuellt saldo: ₹ 105.0
Ange belopp: ₹ 7

Insatt summa: ₹ 7.0
Aktuellt saldo: ₹ 207.0
user1,col2,105.0,col3,col4
user2,col2,207.0,col3,col4
```